# How do I choose the base class when overriding a function in c++?

Tags: c++, overriding, multiple-inheritance

I have two base classes and a class that inherits both base classes.
Both base classes have a virtual function with the same signature, and I want to provide different implementations in the derived class to each virtual function.

```
class A{
    virtual void f() = 0;
}
class B{
    virtual void f() = 0;
}
class Derived:public A, public B{
    void A::f() override{ // Error
        ...
    }
    void B::f() override{ // Error
        ...
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to do this? (I cannot rename the virtual function. Actually the two base classes are generated from the same template class.)

Comment: The derived class inherits the same mix-in template classes with different  arguments. The function f() is actually some function like update(), and I need to define different update function for different arguments.

Comment: May be i am misunterpreting the problem, but consider having one base class with two derived ones instead of what you're currently doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
class AShim : public A {
  void f() override {
    static_cast<T*>(this)->A_f();
  }
};

template <typename T>
class BShim : public B {
  void f() override {
    static_cast<T*>(this)->B_f();
  }
};

class Derived: public AShim<Derived>, public BShim<Derived> {
  void A_f();
  void B_f();
};
```

Comment: It is like an inside out OOP. Having one abstract class with two different implementations seems to be a more straightforward way to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
};
class B {
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
};
class Derived :public A, public B {
public:
    void A::f() {
        cout << "Inside A's version"<<endl;
    }
    void B::f() { 
        cout << "Inside B's version"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived derived;
    cout << "calling A" << endl;
    A *a;
    a = &derived;
    a->f();
    cout << "calling B" << endl;
    B *b;
    b = &derived;
    b->f();
}
```

Works fine for me. No need to explicitly mention override keyword as pure virtual functions will be overridden by virtue of its default properties.Use base class's scope while defining the functions **as you have already done**. Use **public** access specifier to enable derived classes to override the pure virtual function. That's all.

Comment: @BaguetteGarlique I confirm, this works in MSVC. Still not sure if it is conformant :)

Comment: Yes it is from MSVC

Comment: This uses MSVC-specific extension. Neither [clang](http://rextester.com/UYZUX43532) nor [GCC](http://rextester.com/IVEO71499) accept it.